# CORS doesn't work when GrantResourceOwnerCredentials references System.Web.Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, owin-security

I have a simple (for troubleshooting only) implementation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` where I am overriding the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method like this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
}
```

The first line enables CORS and the second line simply invalidates the context.  When testing using Chrome, this works as expected - I get back a **400 (Bad Request)** when I POST to the token endpoint.

However, the moment I introduce any reference to `System.Web.Helpers.Crypto`, CORS no longer works and I get back **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**  For example CORS fails if I change the above to this:

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
        var salt = System.Web.Helpers.Crypto.GenerateSalt();
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    }
```

This is, of course, a contrived example that I came up with while troubleshooting the problem.  In the actual GrantResourceOwnerCredentials, Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword() is used which causes the exact same problem.  Also, as a test, I quickly wrapped the call to Crypto in another class but the problem persists.

Have I encountered a strange bug?  Any direction with this would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:  Further investigating revealed that this problem apparently occurs with any reference to System.Web.Helpers.  In other words, it is not specific to the System.Web.Helpers.Crypto class.**

Comment: wow this would be a very severe bug if your diagnosis is correct... which makes me think it's probably not correct :)  could you use a tool such as fiddler to intercept the HTTP traffic and share with us what is actually going over the wire?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to use fiddler which helped reveal the underlying problem - an exception is occurring: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or..."  now I just need to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out an exception was occurring before the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header could be written.  Stepping through the code did not reveal the exception.  However, once I used fiddler, as recommended by @Robert Levy, I saw the full response which contained the exception - "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers'".  I tracked the problem down to web.config where the `dependentAssembly` entry for `System.Web.Helpers` had the wrong version number:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

`newVersion` was set to `3.0.0.0` but the version of the assembly is `2.0.0.0`.  Making this change in web.config fixed the problem.